# How can i aggregate all txt file with one command for cracking?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, aircrack-ng

I wanted to find passphrase from `.cap` file and `.txt` file (Password Dictionary). But I have too many `.txt` file's there. Can I use those file one by one for cracking? My command is given below: I tried this way, but it did not work

```bsh
aircrack-ng -a2 -b [bssid] -w /home/kali/Downloads/Wordlist/*.txt  /home/kali/Desktop/*.cap
```

Answer (score 3):

`aircrack-ng` -w parameter only accepts a single filename.  The man page clearly shows this

```
-w <words>
    Path to a dictionary file for wpa cracking. Specify "-" to use stdin.
```

You could consider combining all your dictionaries into a single file `sort -u dictionary1 dictionary2 dictionary3 >bigdictionary`

Or you could consider multiple runs of `aircrack-ng`, specifying a different dictionary file each time.

Comment: I applied this command [aircrack-ng -a2 -b {BSSID} sort -u /home/kali/Downloads/8dig5milup.txt  8dig5milup2.txt /home/kali/Desktop/*.cap] It didn't work though

Comment: You would do the sort stuff first.  To produce a dictionary.txt.  And then run `aircrack -w dictionary.txt` plus all the other args as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is automatically feed the content of all of the wordlists to aircrack sequentially.  So if all  of your wordlists are found in the /worddir directory, run:

```
find /worddir -type f -exec cat {} + | aircrack-ng ... -w -
```

The will find each text file in the /worddir directory, cat the file (send the contents to stdout) and pipe it to aircrack-ng reading from stdin.  If you have 100 password files in the /worddir directory, then the single command above will send their contents to aircrack-ng without manual intervention.

Note that the "..." should be replaced with content relevant to your cap/BSSID, etc.